# neo4j BOLT check if connection is open and count number of connections

Tags: python, neo4j, server, connection

Using the BOLT Neo4j driver in python:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost",
                                 auth=basic_auth('neo4j', 'password'),
                                 encrypted=True,
                                 trust=TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE)
session = driver.session()
```

Can I see if a connection is already open using a python command?
Can I see how many connections are open?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API to do this. Bear in mind also that session != connection; the former is an API abstraction, the latter an implementation detail.

Can I ask what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I actually wanted to check if a session is already existent. If not, I want to open one. There is also a max_poolsize of sessions so I wanted to be able to check how many sessions are open at the same time.

Comment: In the (almost released) 1.2 series API, we decouple sessions and connections even further. A session becomes a lazy wrapper for a connection; one is acquired from the pool on BEGIN and released back on COMMIT. This way, you could maintain 50 sessions but only 10 connections. The (internal) connection pool manages connections for you, essentially doing already what you're trying to achieve.